# Can i use the (facebook) parse library with google DART?

Tags: dart, parse-platform

I found this on the DART page.

JsObject and the context getter#
Use the top-level context getter to access the global object in JavaScript. For example, if your JavaScript code has a top-level Point variable, your Dart code can use it like this:

var obj = context['Point'];
Calling context returns a JsObject, which represents a proxy of a JavaScript object.

The JsObject class provides ways to get references to JavaScript objects, get and set object properties, and invoke JavaScript constructors, functions and methods.

Can i call the parse.js library in a similar way?

I am new to dart and parse. I want to use parse for this project.How Will parse + dart affect performance?

Comment: Add a link for parse.js?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. With [dart:js](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/#dart-js) you can use any js library from Dart.

Comment: are you 100% sure ? I am going to go through a good learning curve so just reconfirming

Comment: yes. I created the Dart js wrapper for _google maps_ and it works really well.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess is that DART allows curl like command interface to Pull from 3rd party REST API's.... You simply get instance of [DART.HttpClient](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/#dart%3aio.HttpClient) and issue parse.com.REST commands.

If you can issue curl type CLI within DART and can handle the http response then you can access the full set of Parse.com REST features.

I access parse in this way - altho from android, not dart - and its great. All async, can use thread pool controlled http clients...

See the [Rest manual](https://parse.com/docs/rest) and look for sample apps on github